# How to download a file from sharepoint using O365 python lib

Tags: dataframe, sharepoint, download, python-o365

can anyone please help me with how to download a file from SharePoint? I've been going through this code all day and haven't figured anything out. I can access a specific file and its URL. However, when I try to download it using the code below, it gives me a 401 error even though the token is correct (I've tried both access and refresh tokens). I tryed it also load into dataframe but without success.

token handling
token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='my_folder', token_filename='my_token.txt')

scopes
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', 'offline_access']

setup connection
credentials = (CLIENT_ID, SECRET_ID)
account = Account(credentials=credentials, auth_flow_type='authorization', scopes=scopes,
token_backend=token_backend, tenant_id=TENANT_ID)
conn = Connection(credentials)

connect to cloud
if not account.is_authenticated: # will check if there is a token and has not expired
account.authenticate()
else:
token_backend.check_token()
account.con.refresh_token()

## Get data from SharePoint site

sp_site = account.sharepoint().get_site('root', '/sites/mysite)

## Get SharePoint lists

lists = sp_site.get_lists()

```
# Print SharePoint lists
for sharepoint_list in lists:
    print(f"Name: {sharepoint_list.name}")
```

And when I find the file, I wanted to download it like this:

access_token = token_backend.get_token()

```
# Headers with access token
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

# Download file
response = requests.get(file_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

And after that I get 401 ... Can anyone help me? Thank you guys